# Finding a basis for a space of solutions.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $M,N\in \mathbb{R^4}, M=\{(x,y,z,t):2x-y+3z-t=0\}, N=\{x-y-z-t=0\}$

to find a basis for $M\cap N$, we solve the set of equations $2x-y+3z-t=0$ and $x-y-z-t=0$ to obtain $\{(-4,-5,1,0),(0,1,0-1)\}$

I think this is good. Now I need to add another vector such that these 2 vectors and the one I find form a basis for $M$, how do I go about doing this? If it was for a basis of $\mathbb{R^4}$ I know how to do this, form the matrix with the appropriate columns and check for non-singularity.

Comment: You can find a basis for $M$, from the equation. After that, you can use the fact that equivalent matrices generate the same row space.

Answer (score 1):

The set $M$ is define by $t=2x-y+3z$, so: 
$$M=\{(x,y,z,2x-y+3z)\}=\operatorname{gen}\{(1,0,0,2), (0,1,0,-1), (0,0,1,3)\}$$

Let $A=\begin{pmatrix} 1&0&0&2\\0&1&0&-1\\0&0&1&3 \end{pmatrix}$.

Now, the solution of the system ($M\cap N$) can be expresssed as: $z=\frac{-x}{4}$, $t=\frac{5x}{y}-y$, this is:
$$M\cap N = \{(x,y,\frac{-x}{4}, \frac{5x}{4}-y)\}=\operatorname{gen}\{v_1= (1,0,\frac{-1}{4},\frac{5}{4}), v_2= (0,1,0,-1)\}$$

Choose a new vector: $v_3=(0,0,1,3)$ (note that this is a row vector of $A$, linearly independent with $v_1$ and $v_2$), then the matrix:

$B=\begin{pmatrix} 1&0&\frac{-1}{4}& \frac{5}{4}\\0&1&0&-1\\0&0&1&3 \end{pmatrix}$ is equivalent to $A$, this means that $\{v_1, v_2, v_3\}$ is a basis for $M$.